# Get rid of raster grid cells that are less than 1

Tags: qgis, raster

I'm using QGIS to work with raster data. I have a raster dataset of a country where each grid cell is assigned a number 1-100. However, the raster is in the format of a rectangle based on the extent of the file, so all of the cells outside of the borders of the country are assigned a 0. I cannot figure out how to create a GeoTIFF that excludes these cells that have a value less than 1. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to set cells with value 0 transparent. Check layer properties "Transparency" tab and add an entry for the value 0.